# Как сделать проверку поля на заполнение в случае с непустым VALUE?

Tags: javascript

Есть INPUT, в котором при фокусе текст пропадает.

```
<input id="name_input" name="name" type="text" class="input" onblur='if(this.value=="") this.value="Введите Ваше имя:"' onfocus='if(this.value=="Введите Ваше имя:") this.value=""' value="Введите Ваше имя:"/>
```

Для проверки на заполнение используется [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://2develop.ru/jquery/proverka-poley-s-pomoshtyyu-jquery.html).

Если использовать placeholder, то проблем нет и плагин проверяет поле.
Если же используется input со скриптом для исчезновения текста при фокусе,
код которого представлен выше, то плагин считает input заполненным, так как
value имеет заданное значение. Как можно сделать, чтобы плагин значение
value не воспринимал?

Comment: не вешайте события в html разметке, особенно при использовании jQuery.

Comment: Хорошо, если событие не в HTML-разметке, то суть вопроса всё-равно не меняется.

Comment: Так если нет проблем с placeholder, то зачем эти костыли? Если Вам нужно убирать placeholder при фокусе, то это не проблема.

Comment: Потому-что placeholder в моём случае не подходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все очень просто. Используйте фоновое изображение.

**Вариант А (фоновая картинка)**
**[Посмотреть рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/X5PTN/1/).**

*Допустим, есть вот такой input:*

```
<input id="name_input" name="name" type="text" class="input" value=""/>
```

*И есть вот такие стили для него:*

```
#name_input {
    background: url(картинка_с_надписью_%введите_ваше_имя%.png) no-repeat left;
    height: 18px; /* Тут ваше значение. Учитывайте высоту фоновой картинки */
    width: 200px; /* Тут ваше значение. Учитывайте ширину фоновой картинки */
}
```

*Напишем простую функцию для смены фоновой картинки:*

```
var name_input = document.querySelector('#name_input'), // Наш input
    background = name_input.style.background;           // Текущая фоновая картинка

/* При потере фокуса показываем фоновую картинку, если input был пустой */
name_input.onblur = function() {
    if (this.value === "") {
        this.style.background = background;
    }
}

/* Во время фокуса прячем фоновую картинку */
name_input.onfocus = function() {
    this.style.background = "#ffffff"; /* Или "transparent" */
}
```

**Вариант Б (placeholder)**
**[Посмотреть рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/X5PTN/3/).**

*Допустим, есть вот такой input:*

```
<input id="name_input" name="name" type="text"
       class="input" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя:" value=""/>
```

*Напишем простую функцию для смены значения placeholder'a:*

```
var name_input = document.querySelector('#name_input'),
    placeholder = name_input.getAttribute('placeholder');

/* При потере фокуса показываем placeholder, если input был пустой */
name_input.onblur = function() {
    if (this.value === "") {
        this.setAttribute('placeholder', placeholder);
    }
}

/* Во время фокуса прячем placeholder */
name_input.onfocus = function() {
    this.setAttribute('placeholder', '');
}
```

Comment: тоесть без картинки никак?

Comment: Или картинка, или placeholder.  
Можно еще поизвращаться с новыми элементами и абсолютным позиционированием, но, на мой взгляд, этот вариант будет хуже.

Answer (score 0):

Кроссбраузерное решение с placeholder на чистом CSS:

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: transparent;
}

input:focus:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: transparent;  
}

input:focus::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: transparent;  
}

input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: transparent;  
}
```